# How to deal with the child who is embrassed to see her parent in her school because the parent can't speak English?

Tags: language, adult-child

In India, unfortunately, the English language is given a much higher preference over the native one. The people who speak English are "looked up" as compared to those who can't.

Recently, on TV, I saw an advertisement of an English tuition class where it was shown that a 5th grader was grumbling at her mother (a housewife) saying that she had made her feel insulted in the school in front of her English speaking friend's parents (during parent teacher meet up) since she couldn't speak English (and was talking in Hindi) and everyone else present there could (and was talking in English).

It was shown in advertisement that this incident made the mother think about taking English tuition classes to prevent her child from further embarrassments.

***What should a parent's reaction be in such cases?***

Comment: This is a classic case of the TV advertisement appealing to our insecurities, and not actual real life.

Comment: @Dave while that may be true (it's the most effective form of advertising) those insecurities usually reflect a de-facto stage of society. I don't know much about India, but I know in the US, girls over a certain weight are rarely considered popular in school. So ads that appeal to that insecurity are effective, but the insecurity only exists because of the real life application. (I should point out I'm not in any way defending the notion that that's how we should be judging people, just stating observations of what occurs.)

Answer (score 2):

Any answer would only be an opinion, Learning English would be a good skill to have and would make it easier for her daughter on such occasions. But i don't see why it should make any difference, Speaking English does not make them any better than someone who cant speak English and her mother shouldn't have to learn another language just so her daughter will be more comfortable at parent teacher days. Every parent is embarrassing to there child at some point in there life, that's just how things are. Just my opinion, many will have different views.

Comment: So true - "Every parent is embarassing to their child at some point in their life"